# Interface to modify an abstract attribute

Tags: c++, oop

```
class AbstractShape;
class RectangularShape : public AbstractShape
{
   void setWidth(double v);
   void setLength(double v);
};

class CircleShape : public AbstractShape
{
   void setRadius(double v);
};

class PolygonalShape : public AbstractShape
{
   void addPoint(Point p);
};

class Element
{
   protected:
   AbstractShape* _shape; //RectangularShape, PolygonalShape or CircleShape
};
```

I want to create methods in Element to modify the shape _shape of Element ( ie if the shape is Rectangular I have to be able to change the length and the width, otherwise I have to be able to add a Point to the polygonal shape etc ).

For instance I cannot declare a setLength method because setLength as only a meaning if _shape is a RectangularShape. A solution would be to subclass Element in RectangularElement, PolygonalElement, CircularElement but I would like to avoid this solution.
Do you see another way to do that ?

Comment: The visitor pattern?

Comment: A rectangle should be a polygon as well, consider adding a layer of indirection to morph the polygon

Comment: @user1482030 so you want a fat interface?

Comment: I think that you need to provide a hypothetical use of `Element` so we can see how you would use it. Then we can answer your question (without any further information, I'd say a solution which is usually considered bad practice: add a virtual function to AbstractShape, so you can and differentiate between different types with dynamic_cast)

Comment: @StoryTeller please elaborate

Comment: If `Element` must work on `Shape`, but `Shape` shouldn't have a concept of shape-specific sizes (like `length`, `radius`, `width/height`), then why does `Element` depend on `Shape`? What should `Element` be doing with the shape?

Comment: @Vince Emigh Consider that Element represents a 2D element, and is used to render a shape on the screen. The shape can be manually modified, so Element must provide an interface to edit the shape.

Comment: You'd need to abstract more to be able to edit all shapes using the same interface. `AbstractShape` should only contain behaviors that all shapes conform. This could lead to issues, as the only way to properly modify a curved shape AND a polygon is to allow modification of the points that make up the boundary, which the impl probably wouldn't be pretty. What uses `Element`? You can expose `Element<T extends AbstractShape>#modify(T shape)` then create `CurvedElement extends Element<CurvedShape>`, where `CurvedShape` exposes `setRadius`, or something along those lines. Show how `Element` is used

Answer (score 0):

May be you could do something like following :

```
class Shape
{
   // ....
   virtual void setWidth(double v) { /* not implemented, throw error ? */ }
   virtual void setLength(double v){ /* not implemented, throw error ? */}
   virtual void setRadius(double v){ /* not implemented, throw error ? */}
   virtual void addPoint(Point p)  { /* not implemented, throw error ? */}
  //....
};


class RectangularShape : public Shape
{
   void setWidth(double v) override ;
   void setLength(double v) override;
};

class CircleShape : public Shape
{
   void setRadius(double v) override ;
};

class PolygonalShape : public Shape
{
   void addPoint(Point p) override;
};

class Element
{
   protected:
   Shape* _shape; //Any shape
};
```

Calling *meaningless* function on a `_shape` will print a message or assert .

Answer (score 0):

Other than basic fat interface implementation I mentioned, if you don't want to pollute your abstract base class for whatever reason, one possible solution is to use a fat interface on another class and [capability queries](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Capability_Query)

```
class AbstractShape {};

class RectangularShape : public AbstractShape
{
public:
   void setWidth(double v);
   void setLength(double v);
};

class CircleShape : public AbstractShape
{
public:
   void setRadius(double v);
};

class PolygonalShape : public AbstractShape
{
public:
   void addPoint(Point p);
};

class Element {
public:
    void setWidth(double);
    void setLength(double);
    void setRadius(double);
    void addPoint(Point);
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractShape> shape; 
};
```

And the implementation of `setWidth()` for example could look like this

```
void Element::setWidth(double val) {
    if (auto rectangle = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(this->shape.get())) {
        rectangle->setWidth(val);
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error{"This type does not implement setWidth()"};
    }
}
```

---

Also note that you probably want to use a `std::unique_ptr` and not a raw pointer.

Comment: So it is a "good" design to add methods that can be meaningless if shape doesn't have the correct dynamic type ?

Comment: @user1482030 most of the times you don't have much choice.  In this case you don't seem to have much choice.  That is why I suggested adding those meaningless functions in another class, and not the base class, this keeps the base class "correct" as much as possible I guess.  So now you can add a `getArea()` function for example